# Iterating Through an NSArray

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, fast-enumeration

Can someone help me fix my code here. I am trying to do something simple iterate through the whole array that has NSString's in it convert them to NSIntegers and assign them to a NSInteger variable.

```
 for  (NSInteger *itemF in myNSArray) {
     //WHERE "slotA" is an NSInteger and "itemF" is stored as an NSString and I wanna conver to NSInteger 
     //and store is in the var.
     slotA=itemF;          
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
for (NSString *string in array)
{
  NSInteger integer = [string integerValue]; 
}
```